# Scrollbar doesn't appear when adding <li> dynamically by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have `ul` list in `div` and if I set div `height` and `overflow-y`

It becomes scrollable.

```
 <div class="inner" style="height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;font-size:18px;">         
     <ul id="mainul">
       <li>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p>This is the tweet frist<br>
            tweet<br>
            tweet<br> 
            test<p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>This is the tweet that's second<br>
            tweet<br>
            tweet<br> 
            test<br>
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

However when I add items by `append` of jquery.

```
$("#mainul").append(`
            <li>
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p>Add this few times<br>
            tweet<br>
            tweet<br> 
            test<br>
            </div>
            </div>
            </li>`);
```

There never appears scroll bar.

Is this the way to make scrollbar for dynamically added `<li>` ?

How should I solve this??

Comment: Do you want the `li` to be scrollable? I didn't understand... Could you provide a snippet with [mcve] ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8L1pk6wx/ Works fine!

Comment: @Michelangelo not saying that this happened here, but you need to take care when editing questions with code typos, because sometimes the typo is exactly the issue, so he post a code and then you edit it and OP's code starts to work without OP even know what happened, making him get downvotes because of "not reproducible"

Comment: @CalvinNunes Get your point, was quick with the edit button. The code would throw an error in the console though with that typo and looking at the reputation of OP that would be a rookie mistake and actually a bit lazy...to just throw it here on SO without looking in your console.

Comment: yes, of course, in this case here, it makes sense

Comment: So, is there an issue here or was it just a typo?  If there's an issue, please create a snippet that demonstrates the issue.  You may find in doing so, you find your issue.   Does not show the new li? does it show but the outer div gets bigger?

Comment: It was not because of typo, typo happened when I copied and simplified the code . However it was my mistake. sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few syntax errors in your code.

You were also missing the closing quote in `$("#mainul")` though Michelangelo edited it.

This works below.

```js
$("#mainul").append(`
            <li>
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p>
                    Add this few times<br>
                    tweet<br>
                    tweet<br> 
                    test<br>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner" style="height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;font-size:18px;">         
     <ul id="mainul">
       <li>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p>This is the tweet frist<br>
            tweet<br>
            tweet<br> 
            test<p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>This is the tweet that's second<br>
            tweet<br>
            tweet<br> 
            test<br>
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```